How to troubleshoot when pip does not show all package versions
I want to install a specific version of a package through pip.
However, when trying to install pytorch v2.4.1 on my M1 Macbook with pip install torch==2.4.1 I get:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.4.1 (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.4.1

Presumably Python version, OS or Hardware is not compatible with versions >2.2.2 of pytorch. How can I work out which it is?
I've tried with different Python versions, so I suspect it's hardware. pip index versions torch does not list versions above 2.2.2

Which version of Python are you running? How have you tried different Python versions?

I tried multiple versions of Python (3.7-3.11), installed in different conda environments.

Right - Conda is a very different ecosystem (and you should've probably mentioned it originally). https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ has specific instructions to install Torch on Conda: conda install pytorch::pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch

I did not realize that using python within a conda environment could have any impact on which versions of a package pip will serve you. I still don't understand how!

Attempt install with increased verbosity, like this:
pip install torch==2.4.1 -vv

Now there will be log messages which say why some versions have been excluded by your package finder when crawling the index, e.g.:
$ pip install torch==2.4.1 -vv | grep Skipping
...
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/49/4a0a8b19ce8f9bf32fcab4e863c7e2366f519f9826c84ca250567b11a014/torch-2.5.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (from https://pypi.org/simple/torch/) (requires-python:>=3.8.0)
...

There will likely be many versions excluded by wheel compatibility tags due to mismatched platform and Python verson.
For torch wheels specifically, you may want to look at the PyTorch index instead of at PyPI. There are a lot more options available - https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/

Thank you. Wheel compatibility tags is definitely the keyword I was looking for, and -vv would have helped me identify the problem. I uninstalled my old conda (4.12.3) install and installed a newer version, and now the problem is gone, so I don't know exactly what was failing before!
